# Swift3, Как рассчитать запуск или какой аудиоплеер выбрать?

Tags: xcode, swift, аудио, swift3

У AVAudioPlayer есть нужная мне функция - воспроизводить аудио через определенное время **play(atTime:**

```
let shortStartDelay: TimeInterval = 0.1
let now = player.deviceCurrentTime
player.play(atTime: now + shortStartDelay)
```

Получается **player.deviceCurrentTime**  - это **TimeInterval**, к примеру сейчас он у меня равен *242556.425833583*

Кто нибудь знает, как он его высчитывает?

Мне нужно брать системное время с устройства **Date()**, прибавлять к нему, допустим, 4 секунды и делать что то типа:

```
player.play(atTime: Date() + 4)
```

Как так сделать?
Или подскажите какой-нибудь другой плеер который так может...

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!
deviceCurrentTime - это всегда now. У меня на симуляторе он обнуляется только после перезагрузки.

```
let systemDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 4)//Какая-то дата
let timeinterval = systemDate.timeIntervalSince(Date())
audioPlayer.play(atTime: audioPlayer.deviceCurrentTime+timeinterval+4)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я заметил что на разных устройствах deviceCurrentTime высчитывается не синхронно, где-то быстрее, а где-то медленнее. Из-за этого не получается сделать синхронный запуск на двух устройствах через длительное время(даже через 5 мин), только если синхронизировать deviceCurrentTime на обоих девайсах непосредственно прям перед самим запуском. Для меня важна каждая миллисекунда, а синхронизировать каждый запуск не хочется конечно)